# Why is my Android list item background image displaying with a dark overlay?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme

This is my Android `list_item` layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingRight="?android:attr/scrollbarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/list_bg">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_displayname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the `list_bg` image:

[image]

and yet here is what it looks like when shown in Android emulator:

[image]

I can see that the background is being applied because there is a slight gradient effect to it, but I have no idea where this black overlay is coming from!

Comment: Is your background image with transparency?

Comment: It is a JPG so I do not think so

Comment: Jpg ? Is it well supported by the Android platform ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried a different image to see if that one does the same thing? to me it looks like it is creating the image behind the list in your `RelativeLayout` and your textview background is on top. since you are setting it to fill the width of the row, i bet if you just set to `wrap_content` you would see it behind there

try putting the image as your `TextView` background instead